# Cannot access field multiple sub queries deep

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I'm getting an error trying to access a selected field in a sub query of a sub query. It says “Unkown column in where clause”. I have other sub queries as well using that same field and they work perfectly. The problem only seems to occur when I try to access the field in sub query within a subquery.

The simplified version of my query

```
SELECT r.id, 
 (SELECT min(begindatum) 
  FROM ((SELECT begindatum FROM reservatiekamer 
         WHERE reservatieId = r.id) UNION 
        (SELECT begindatum FROM reservatiefaciliteit 
         WHERE reservatieId = r.id)) as bg)
as begindatum
FROM reservatie r
```

The error

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'r.id' in 'where clause'
```

The background story, I'm trying to select the start date of a reservation that exists of multiple reservations of rooms and facilities (2 different tables).

Comment: Did you mean `FROM reservatie AS r`?

Comment: Isn't  AS optional in MySQL?

Comment: AS is indeed optional in MySQL. I use the "r" in many places in my full query and besides inside a sub query of a subquery it doesn't cause any problems.

Answer (score 1):

If the subqueries always return exactly one value, you can use `least()`:

```
SELECT r.id, 
       least((SELECT begindatum FROM reservatiekamer WHERE reservatieId = r.id),
             (SELECT begindatum FROM reservatiefaciliteit WHERE reservatieId = r.id)
            ) as begindatum
FROM reservatie r;
```

Actually, this variation will work better:

```
SELECT r.id, 
       least(COALESCE((SELECT MIN(begindatum) FROM reservatiekamer WHERE reservatieId = r.id), 0),
             COALESCE((SELECT MIN(begindatum) FROM reservatiefaciliteit WHERE reservatieId = r.id), 0)
            ) as begindatum
FROM reservatie r;
```

This assumes that the values are always positive, which is why the `0` is there.  Another value might be more appropriate.

Finally, you can move the logic to the `from` clause:

```
SELECT r.id,
       LEAST(COALESCE(rk.minbd, rf.minbd), COALESCE(rf.minbd, rk.minbd)) as begindatum
FROM reservatie r LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT reservatieId, MIN(begindatum) as minbd
      FROM reservatiekamer
      GROUP BY reservatieId
     ) rk
     ON r.id = rk.reservatieId LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT reservatieId, MIN(begindatum) as minbd
      FROM reservatiefaciliteit
      GROUP BY reservatieId
     ) rf
     ON r.id = rf.reservatieId;
```

The `coalesce()` is the `least()` is intended to return one value if the other is `NULL`.

Comment: The first and the third query give me an error. The second one doesn't give me the results I need, on 15 records, 13 of them have "0" as begindatum and only 2 have an actual date.

Comment: Error at the first query: #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row 
Error at the third query: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;